# Index method for a column used only for ordering

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table `product_images` with a  foreign key `product_id` and integer field `order` to manualy set order of product's images. Knowing that the table will be used only like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_images
WHERE product_id = ?
ORDER BY "order"
```

-- what is the optimal index method for `product_id` and `order`?

Is that enough?:

```
CREATE INDEX product_images_unique_order
ON "product_images"("product_id", "order");
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/35d80/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should do it.

PostgreSQL might decide not to use that index, depending on how many rows you have, how many images any given product_id has, and how scattered about the table all of the rows with the same product_id are, and how wide the rows of the product_images table are; plus many other things.

But by having that index you provide PostgreSQL with the opportunity to use it.

Comment: Thanks! What about the index algorithm? Does the default b-tree suit my task? Looking at other options, I guess yes, but if there's a way to tweak it to get the best performance for my exact case (ascending sort only), I'd like to know.

Comment: btree should be best.  I don't think any of the others would help at all for that case.